# Error when using Collections.sort() with ArrayList and Class. (JAVA)

Tags: java, class, sorting, arraylist

I'm actually trying to order an ArrayList using external sorting (I know it's easier than this, but my teacher wants it like this).

I have the next code:

```
//MainClass

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cotxe coche1 = new Car("Opel","Corsa",200);
        Cotxe coche2 = new Car ("Ferrari","Italia",200);
        Cotxe coche3 = new Car ("Porsche","Cayenne",200);

        ArrayList<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();

        list.add(car1);
        list.add(car2);

        Collections.sort(list, new OrderCarByModel());
    }

//COMPARATOR CLASS

public interface Comparator <Car>{
    int compare(Car c1, Car c2);
    boolean equals(Object obj);
}

//ORDERCARBYMODEL CLASS

public class OrderCarByModel implements Comparator<Car> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Car c1, Car c2) {
        return c1.getModel().compareTo(c2.getModel());
    }

//CAR CLASS ONLY HAVE 3 ATTRIBUTES. BRAND, MODEL AND PRICE, IT'S A PRETTY SIMPLE CLASS.
```

The error comes in the "Collections.sort(list, new OrderCarByModel());" in the MainClass.

[Sorry for the translation, I just translated the code in the post but not in the error picture, "Cotxe" means "Car" and "OrdenarCocheModelo" means "OrderCarByModel".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bN0o.png)

Answer (score 2):

`public interface Comparator <Car>{`

You should not have created your own interface named `Comparator`. Remove it (and the class files). `OrderCarByModel` must implement [`java.util.Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to work with [`Collections.sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: When I implement Comparator it doesn't let me to modify the 2 Object type objects the function receives to Car, so I can compare only 1 attribute (getModel) and order it in an alphabetic way.